# How does Guy know the world is ending?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-croods

In [The Croods](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0481499/) the girl *Eep* meets *Guy* who is travelling to the mountain, because the *world is ending*.

Here is a scene from the film that shows *Guy* telling *Eep* [the world is ending](http://movies.yahoo.com/video/croods-meet-guy-193653923.html).

How does *Guy* know that the world is ending?

Comment: I got the impression he'd seen it somewhere before? I'd need to re-watch before I could answer properly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is based on Guy's theory that the earthquakes are a symptom of *The End* (of the world) and that heading to higher ground is the best way to possibly escape from the calamity. He's something of a cave-scientist and this is the kind of thing that cave-scientists do. It also contrasts his out-of-the-box thinking against that of stick-in-the-mud Grug.